# Graduated brightness adjustment in Windows for TN monitor

Tags: windows

Is there any way to add a global graduated brightness filter in Windows, like f.lux filters out blue light? The top of my monitor is brighter than the bottom so i would like to make the top slighly brighter and the bottom slightly darker.

Comment: tbh, that sounds like the monitor's backlight's on its way out. That *typically* shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs *some* tweaking for your specific monitor but in *theory* I could get this to work with a few small tools and some sneakiness.

I've not tried this for gaming (and it probably wouldn't work) but you could in use a tool that overlaid a gradient over your desktop then played with the gradient, and transparency.

I created a gradient like this. In paint.net you'd want to create a new image the same size as your screen, *add* a new layer, and use the colour picker to pick that 'colour' as a secondary. Then create a gradient from black to that, delete the base layer, and save this.  You'd want something like the image below. The *thickness* and *gradient* would depend on your specific desire for darkening.

[image]

I then picked [custom desktop logo](http://customdesktoplogo.wikidot.com/) off of this [software recommendations question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1767/display-half-transparent-ghost-image-over-other-windows) and used that to overlay my screen - its a portable app so you really can't break anything. By adjusting the gradient and transparency, you could adjust brightness top to bottom, or by overlaying, say a circular or other shaped gradient or image, selectively 'dim' a screen.

And while I can't get a gif of *dynamically* altering the effect on the fly, this is roughly what it looks like before and after

[image]

Tested and working great on windows 10. Has *some* oddness in windows XP but who uses that these days, right?

Comment: I wonder if an ICC profile would be more robust here than a screen overlay.

Comment: Do ICC profiles do that? I thought they were *general* for the whole monitor. Or how you can create one manually.

Comment: I'm not sure! If I knew, I'd post an answer. Was just an offhand comment in case someone else knew. Would make sense for it to be possible, though, assuming monitors are generally nonuniform (and there's the whole point of calibration).

Comment: I don't think the caliberator I borrowed did that, though it did pretty graphs of consistancy.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for. I'd be careful in games though because it might get you banned. Could be used to overlay crosshairs etc.

Comment: I was thinking more how games tend to take over the entire display exclusively, and an overlay wouldn't likely work, on full screen mode. I never considered the cheating angle though